# I cant understand what's wrong with my python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, object

The part with the goblin works but the part with the elf doesn't.

```
#importing the random module
import random

#creating the game object class
class GameObject:
    class_name = ""
    desc = ""
    objects = {}

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        GameObject.objects[self.class_name] = self
    
    #defining the description 
    def get_desc(self):
        return self.class_name + "\n" + self.desc

#creating the goblin class
class Goblin(GameObject):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.class_name = "goblin"
        self.health = 3
        self._desc = "A foul creature"
        super().__init__(name)

    @property
    def desc(self):
        if self.health >= 3:
            return self._desc
        elif self.health == 2:
            x = random.randint(13, 35)
            health_line = "You struck and dealt " + str(x) + " damage!"
        elif self.health == 1:
            y = 40 - random.randint(13, 35)
            health_line = "You rushed and dealt " +str(y) + " damage! \n Goblin activated effect Rage!"
        elif self.health <= 0:
            health_line = "It is dead."
        return self._desc + "\n" + health_line

    @desc.setter
    def desc(self, value):
        self._desc = value
        
#creating the goblin object
goblin = Goblin("Gobbly")
        
#creating the elf class
class Elf(GameObject):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.class_name = "Elf"
        self.health = 5
        self._desc = "A strong warlock"
        super().__init__(name)
    
    @property
    def desc(self):
        if self.health >= 5:
            return self._desc
        elif self.health == 4:
            x = random.randint(20, 50)
            health_line = " You struck and dealt " + str(x) + " damage!"
        elif self.health == 3:
            x = random.randint(20, 40)
            health_line = " You countered and dealt " + str(x) + " damage!"
        elif self.health == 2:
            y = 40 - random.randint(20, 50)
            health_line = "You rushed and dealt " +str(y) + " damage! \n Elf activated effect Sectum Sempra!!"
        elif self.health == 1:
            y = 40 - random.randint(20, 50)
            health_line = " You struck and dealt " + str(x) + " damage!"
        elif self.health <= 0:
            health_line = "It is dead."
        return self._desc + "\n" + health_line

    @desc.setter
    def desc(self, value):
        self._desc = value

#creating an elf object
elf = Elf("Elfy")

#defining the hit verb
def hit(noun):
    if noun in GameObject.objects:
        thing = GameObject.objects[noun]
        if type(thing) == Goblin:
            thing.health -= 1
            if thing.health <= 0:
                msg = "You killed the goblin!"
            else:
                msg = "You hit the {}".format(thing.class_name)
        elif type(thing) == Elf:
            thing.health -= 1
            if thing.health <= 0:
                msg = "You killed the elf!"
            else:
                msg = "You hit the {}".format(thing.class_name)
    else:
        msg = "There is no {} here.".format(noun)
    return msg

#defining the examine verb
def examine(noun):
    if noun in GameObject.objects:
        return GameObject.objects[noun].get_desc()
    else:
        return "There is no {} here.".format(noun)

#getting input
def get_input():
    command = input(": ").split()
    verb_word = command[0]
    if verb_word in verb_dict:
        verb = verb_dict[verb_word]
    else:
        print("Unknown verb {}".format(verb_word))
        return

    if len(command) >= 2:
        noun_word = command[1]
        print(verb(noun_word))
    else:
        print(verb("nothing"))

#defining the say verb
def say(noun):
    return 'You said "{}"'.format(noun)

#the verbs
verb_dict = {
    "say": say,
    "examine": examine,
    "hit": hit
}

while True:
    get_input()
```

It's supposed to say |you hit the elf| when I type |hit elf| like how it says |you hit the goblin| when I type |hit goblin|

I just started learning oop in python and some parts are confusing. If anyone understands, please help me fix the code.

Comment: It's just a typo: "Elf" has a capital E. It is easy to find out with a little debugging. Just `print(GameObject.objects)` and the problem gets visible immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first elif refers to else if , that simply means that if statement is activated then the elif statement gets skipped . So try replacing elif with if . If problem still continues , reply.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that you need to check the type of the object here:

```
def hit(noun):
    if noun in GameObject.objects:
        thing = GameObject.objects[noun]
        thing.health -= 1
        if thing.health <= 0:
            msg = "You killed the {}!".format(thing.class_name.lower())
        else:
            msg = "You hit the {}".format(thing.class_name)
    else:
        msg = "There is no {} here.".format(noun)
    return msg
```

Comment: How else can I do it?

Comment: Just spotted that I forgot to remove the if line of the type check, this function should do the same as your hit function did, but without checking whether the object is goblin or elf

Comment: I removed the if statement and changed the indentation accordingly but it still wouldn't work

Comment: It would help if you could show exactly how your code doesn't work (what happens when elf is hit, what happens when goblin is hit? What errors do you see, if any?) If your code is working (i.e. there are no errors), but doesn't do what you want, that's a different kind of problem

Comment: When I type hit goblin it says you hit the goblin but when I type hit elf it says there is no elf here